# Summation in Wideband vs Averaging in Subband in PMI selection

Tags: matlab

Summation in Wideband vs Averaging in Subband in PMI selection

In MATLAB 5G toolbox, in the hDLPMISelect.m file, we have two different approaches for wideband and subband to find optimum indices for PMI selection.

In the wideband case, we do sum of SINRs across the BWP for all layers for each PMI index. But in the subband case, we average the SINR per RE values across the subband for all the PMI indices.

I was wondering why this is the case? I couldn't find any related material for it.